# If, else if, else statements and logical operators in R and creating functions

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, logical-operators, notation

I have worked on this for two days and simply I am stuck in the mud! I am working on using if, else if and else statements in R

I have created a function to draw 3 random cards for two players to simulate a game

```
face=c("king", "queen", "jack", "ten", "nine", "eight", "seven", "six", "five", "four", "three", "two", "ace")
value=c(13, 12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1) 
deck <-data.frame(face=rep(face,4),
                  suit=c(rep("spades", 13), rep("clubs", 13), rep("diamonds", 13), rep("hearts", 
                  13)),
                  value=rep(value,4))
```

This is the function I created to get their hands

```
get_cards<-function(){
  Player.A<-draw_n_random_cards(deck, 3)
  Player.B<-draw_n_random_cards(deck, 3)
}
```

1 I added up the values of each player's hand to get their scores

```
Sum.Player.A<-sum(Player.A$value)
Sum.Player.B<-sum(Player.B$value)
```

2 If all the cards in the hand are the same suit (all hearts) their sum will be multiplied by 2
#3 If all the cards are the same suit (all aces) there sum will be multiplied by 2 also
Ok, so I created a logical test for my if, else if, else statement

```
combo.1=c("ace", "ace", "ace")
combo.2=c("heart", "heart", "heart")
```

This is my if statement

```
if (Sum.Player.A==combo.1){
  Sum.Player.A<-Sum.Player.A*2
}else{
  Sum.Player.A
}

if(Sum.Player.A==combo.2){
  Sum.Player.A<-Sum.Player.A*2
}else{
  Sum.Player.A
}

if (Sum.Player.B==combo.1){
  Sum.Player.B<-Sum.Player.B*2
}else{
  Sum.Player.B
}

if(Sum.Player.B==combo.2){
  Sum.Player.B<-Sum.Player.B*2
}else{
  Sum.Player.B
}
```

My end result is to write a function that displays each player's hand and declares a winner.

```
winner<-function(){
if(Sum.Player.A<Sum.Player.B){
          "Player B is the winner"
        }else if (Sum.Player.A>Sum.Player.B){
          "Player A is the winner"}else {
           "tie"}
}
```

So my trouble is putting this sequence of functions into a single function to play this game I created.
If I create a function called

```
play_game<-function(){

#1 draw 3 random cards for each player
#2 score their cards
#3 compare their score to delcare a winner
}
```

This is where I have been stuck. I am looking for direction on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added stringsAsFactors=FALSE to the creation of the deck. Draw n random cards draws cards at once, otherwise you risk drawing the same cards (it needs to be done without replacement). Lastly, the winner function takes the sum of A's hand and the sum of B's hand as arguments.

```
face=c("king", "queen", "jack", "ten", "nine", "eight", "seven", "six", "five", "four", "three", "two", "ace")
value=c(13, 12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1) 
deck <-data.frame(face=rep(face,4),
                  suit=c(rep("spades", 13), rep("clubs", 13), rep("diamonds", 13), rep("hearts", 
                                                                                       13)),
                  value=rep(value,4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

get_cards<-function(){
  return(draw_n_random_cards(6))
}

draw_n_random_cards=function(n) {
  s=sample(1:52, 6, replace=FALSE)
  return(deck[s,])
}

winner<-function(A, B){
  if(A<B){
    "Player B is the winner"
  }else if (A>B){
    "Player A is the winner"}else {
      "tie"}
}

play_game=function() {
  cards=draw_n_random_cards()
  Player.A=cards[1:3,]
  Player.B=cards[4:6,]
  Sum.Player.A<-sum(Player.A$value)
  Sum.Player.B<-sum(Player.B$value)
  
  combo.1=c("ace", "ace", "ace")
  combo.2=c("heart", "heart", "heart")
  
  if (identical(Player.A$face, combo.1) | identical(Player.A$suit, combo.2)) {
    Sum.Player.A<-Sum.Player.A*2
  }
  if (identical(Player.B$face, combo.1) | identical(Player.B$suit, combo.2)) {
    Sum.Player.B<-Sum.Player.B*2
  }
  winner(Sum.Player.A, Sum.Player.B)
}
```

On one play of the game:

```
> play_game()
[1] "Player B is the winner"
```

Comment: This makes sense. You create a get cards function that will return 6 cards.